# usar regex na função explode do php

Tags: php, regex

Estou a fazer uma consulta a minha DB, e podemos fazer uma consulta idêntica a esta:

> "olá mundo" "oceano pacifico"

O que acontece, é que posso pesquisar por várias strings ao mesmo tempo:

> **Resultado esperado:**
>
> String1: olá mundo
>
> string2: oceano pacifico

As strings são divididas por um espaço, mas tem que estar entre aspas.

Tenho o seguinte em código:

```
$array_seach = explode($search_word, " ");
```

O problema disto é que ele vai cortar no primeiro espaço em branco que encontrar, em vez de separar as string.
Também já tentei mas sem resultado:

```
$array_seach = explode($search_word, " \"");
$array_seach = explode($search_word, ' \"');
```

Tendo em conta que não sei o número de strings nem o que vem escrito, como posso resolver isto?

Comment: Seu `explode` está ao contrário. Primeiro é o delimitador, depois a palavra. Exemplo: `explode(' ', $search);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui o que você estava querendo da seguinte forma:

```
$string = '"palavra um" "palavra dois" "palavra três"';

$partes = preg_split('/("|"\s+|\s+")/u', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

print_r($partes);
```

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => palavra um
    [1] => palavra dois
    [2] => palavra três
)
```

Não sei se é a expressão regular mais adequada, mas nela estamos utilizando como separador de palavras a áspas`"`, OU a áspas com um espaço `"\s+"` ou um espaço seguido de uma áspa `\s+"`

Exemplo:

http://ideone.com/H6x0j5

Answer (score 4):

A função explode não é apropriada para isso.

Pode obter o resultado que espera com a função `preg_match_all`

```
$str = '"olá mundo" "oceano pacifico"';
if (preg_match_all('~(["\'])([^"\']+)\1~', $str, $arr))
   print_r($arr[2]);
```

resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => olá mundo
    [1] => oceano pacifico
)
```

Caso queira usar a função `explode()`, veja o teste abaixo, o qual retorna o mesmo resultado.

```
$arr = explode('" "',$str);
$arr = array_map( function($v) { return str_replace( '"', '', $v ); }, $arr);

print_r($arr);
```

Obviamente necessita de outras duas funções `array_map()` e `str_replace()`

Particularmente, acho a técnica com `preg_match_all()` mais segura e simples.

Comment: +1 interessante! Vou testar aqui :)

Comment: Daniel, só uma dica. Use o modificador `u` por causa do `UTF-8`, a palavra `olá` perdeu a letra `á` por causa do acento

Comment: Boa dica Wallace! Eu não usei o modificador porque normalmente testo num ambiente com encode e charset já configurado, dispensando o uso de modificadores na maioria dos casos.

Comment: Não sabia que a configuração do ambiente dispensava o uso do modificador `u` oO

Comment: Será que é essa expressão regular que o `SO` faz para poder criar as tags, quando você faz a pergunta? :)